# What is this "normalize.less" I see in F12 Developer Console?

Tags: css, less

I am having trouble finding information on this "normalize.less" thing I'm seeing in the Chrome 76 developer console. At the same spot in Firefox 69's console, it instead shows bootstrap.min.css so I'm guessing it's part of bootstrap, at least in my case. What is it though?

When I hover over it in Chrome, it pops up a filepath pointing to localhost/css/less/normalize.less but I don't have any folders under css, let alone one named less.

I've tried Googling "localhost css less" and "normalize.less" but am mostly finding various GitHub projects I'm not using and a few questions on here asking why less.css isn't working. I have no reason to think it's broken or getting in my way, I just have no idea what it is.

Also, to be clear, any mention here of normalize.css or less.css are from the search results I've seen. I'm focusing on normalize.less. (...they're not somehow the same thing or anything, are they?)

For the purpose of finding/seeing this reference to normalize.less:
[image: Chrome dev console snippet]

What is it, and why did Chrome point me to an apparently non-existent file and folder? (bug?) Is there any relation between normalize.less, normalize.css, and less.css? Heck, what are .less files in general?

Comment: Well, you can click on the `less` tag you added to your question to see what less is :). It's using "source maps", which point to files that were present when the source was built, not when it was deployed or distributed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Chrome devtools show these folders in orange and in italics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43599974/why-does-chrome-devtools-show-these-folders-in-orange-and-in-italics)

Answer (score 2):

This is because the location of the bootstrap CSS file also has a .map file.

This file is used to indicate to the developer which file and which line is the attribute he wants to change, since the bootstrap.min.css file is nothing more than a large compilation of dozens of files.